# Robocopy to Wildcard Directory

Tags: windows, cmd, robocopy

I'd like to robocopy to a wildcard destination with something like `robocopy c:\source\ c:\*estination\`

I could `cd` to `c:\*estination\` then `robocopy c:\source\ .` but what are some other techniques?

Comment: Explain why you need a wildcard target folder and you will get a solution to solve that situation, most likely.

Comment: It's for copying config files to my firefox profile folder, which has a randomly generated name ending in .default. Just curious what other ways there are to do this.

Answer (score 5):

This will give you each profile folder path in turn:

```
@echo off
for /d %%a in ("%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*") do echo "%%a"
pause
```

Comment: What next? How can I use this with robocopy?

Comment: You use a `copy` command and `"%%a"` is your profile folder - at least it is here.  if you want help to use `Robocopy` then supply details about what you need to do.

Comment: Got it working with `for /d %%a in ("%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*") do robocopy . "%%a" /s /xf *.cmd`. Thanks for your help!